# Docker environment variables: How to get environment variables in code files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron, environment-variables

I wanted to ask that I have a docker file and docker compose file. I want to create environment variables like username, password and path for my connectivities. I create my environment variables like this in my docker compose file:

```
  backup:
    container_name: "backup"
    image: "816e6e28c791"
    environment:
      - mongoLink=mongodb://mongo:27017
      - mongoUser=root
      - mongoPassword=example
      - nextcloudLink=http://nextcloud
      - nextcloudUser=admin
      - nextcloudPassword=example
```

Now I wanted to access those variables in cron file which looks like this:

```
0 0 * * * root /backup.sh -u mongodb://mongo:27017 -d ./backup >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

how I can access them. I wanted to replace mongo address to variable. I copied my cron file into container directory.

My docker file:

```
FROM mongo:latest

RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cron
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y zip

ADD /script/container_cronjob /etc/cron.d/container_cronjob
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/container_cronjob
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./script/backup.sh /backup.sh

RUN chmod +x /backup.sh

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

OR

If I create my environment variables in docker file then how I can access them.

Comment: The cron daemon resets the environment for the processes it launches.  The linked question describes several ways to work around this, which generally boil down to dumping the environment at container startup time and then telling crond to load that environment file again.